# Changing the background color of the framed region of a plot

Tags: plotting, color

I frequently generate framed plots like this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to change the background color of the framed region only?

Specifying the `Background` option unfortunately changes the background color of the entire plot, not just the framed region:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image]

Also, is there a way to make figures look like MATLAB's default figure style, i.e. a white background surrounded by a gray frame (see below)?

[image: MATLAB figure]

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303500/mathematica-matlab-like-figure-plot

Comment: The answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303500/mathematica-matlab-like-figure-plot have been move here as a result of merging.

Comment: wow... it has been a while since I've been to stack overflow. But now I come back and my question has been migrated here and given credit to someone else... @Mr.Wizard, what's going on here? How do I find my original post?

Comment: @jmlopez I am new to moderating but I am trying to do the best job I can.  When a duplicate question was posted here (this one) I wanted to combine the two rather than cover old ground.  Even at the time I was uncertain how to handle it; normally I would close the new question as a duplicate of the old, but it was suggested to me to keep the new one instead, and since you appeared to have left StackExchange I did not argue.  Please read the [chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3555483#3555483) to see how this played out.

Comment: @jmlopez I also wasn't entirely aware of how migration and merging worked, and I might have done things differently with greater knowledge.  I don't know why your question was deleted (apparently by the system) rather than simply closed.  I have undeleted it now, but I don't know if the system will leave it that way.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks for the explanation and thank you for restoring my post. One last question though, most of my questions are Mathematica related, does that mean that all of my stackoverflow question will be migrated over here?

Comment: @jmlopez probably not; I and others have been quite selective about having older questions migrated.  There are more migrations for new Mathematica questions being posted on SO.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it appears it was deleted, yet he retains the rep from it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the `Prolog` option with `Scaled` coordinates:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True,
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: Using scaled coordinates lets this work for any `PlotRangePadding`, and with `PlotRangePadding->False`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> -.2, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very helpful.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 26):

After playing around for a while with various graphics and frame options...
I decided to take the simplest option - your polygon one:

```
Framed[Plot[Sin[x] Exp[x], {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, Axes -> False, 
  Prolog -> {White, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}], 
 Background -> LightGray]
```

[image: An example image generated from the above code]

Comment: This works because `Plot` sets `PlotRangeClipping -> True` by default.  (A good choice -- it keeps curves from drawing beyond the frame.)  Using `Scaled` instead of `ImageScaled` would be better, since the `Scaled` coordinate system naturally corresponds to plot range (ie, the region inside the frame.)

Comment: @Brett: Thanks Brett. Using `Scaled` is by far the better choice. Too many graphics/image options and I always forget which is which.

Comment: @Brett and @Simon: I edited my post in order to add a solution based on your ideas. This gives me more control over my custom labels and graphics. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 12):

You could also do:

```
Framed[Plot[{Sin[x] Exp[x], Exp[x]}, {x, 1, 10}, 
       Frame -> True, 
       Axes  -> False, 
       PlotRangePadding -> None, 
       Filling          -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, 
       FillingStyle     -> White], 
       Background       -> LightGray]
```

[image]

**Edit**

I suspected problems when the function is not defined in the full range, but found it is not the case:

```
Framed[Plot[{Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 4}, {x, x > 6}}]}, {x, 1, 10}, 
       Frame -> True, 
       Axes  -> False, 
       PlotRangePadding -> None, 
       Filling          -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, 
       FillingStyle     -> White], 
       Background       -> LightGray]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 The hack even works if you want to fill down in color and have the rest white. `Framed[Plot[{Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 4}, {x, x > 6}}]}, {x, 1, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  Filling -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, FillingStyle -> {White, Blue}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], Background -> LightGray]`

Comment: @Simon Not so well. Try `-x^2` instead of `x^2`

Comment: The problem there is a combination of the `PlotRange` and the default default (0) for `Piecewise`...

Answer (score 7):

While [Eli's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2263/89) is elegantly simple, it has a drawback: the `Prolog` objects are layered on top of `GridLines`, thus a background rectangle covers all the gridlines. So to come over this issue, here is my version of a background-and-frame.

The general background (gray) is defined by the outermost `Frame`'s `Background` option (this way we won't cover `GridLines`), while the outer green frame is defined as a `FilledCurve` (using `ImageScaled` and `Scaled` coordinates), put in an independent `Graphics` object, and displayed with the final plot via `Show`. There is at least one caveat: any options defined for a `Plot` object must be then forwarded to the `Show`, otherwise they mess up the result.

```
Framed[
 Show[
  Graphics[{
    Hue[.3, 1, 1, .5], 
    FilledCurve[{
        {Line[ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
        {Line[Scaled /@ ({{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}})]}
       }],
    }],
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], (* this is the main plot, options given to Show *)
  ImagePadding -> 30, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Red
  ],
 Background -> GrayLevel@.9, FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might wonder why I didn't put the `FilledCurve` into the `Plot`'s `Prolog`: well, `Prolog` cannot handle coordinates that are out of the defined `PlotRange`, thus `ImageScaled` coordinates out of the plot's frame won't show at all.

Comment: This is also a very ellegant solution for those annoying cases where PlotRangeClipping will fail to fully clip the corners of lines when they meet the frame.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I would do it:

```
passepartout[plot_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := With[{
   p = Show[plot, PlotRangePadding -> None]
   },
  Show[Show[
    Graphics[{((Background /. Options[plot]) /. 
        Background -> Transparent), 
      Apply[Rectangle, Transpose[PlotRange /. Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[p]]]}], 
    p, Options[p]],
   opt]
  ]
```

This function should be able to take any Graphics object as its argument "plot". It uses whatever Background plot has been given beforehand, and then adds the frame according to the options Background and ImagePadding supplied to the passepartout function.

For example, start with a plot

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, Background -> Yellow]
```

(I added a yellow background, but that's just for illustration and is completely optional). To get what you're looking for, just say

```
passepartout[p, ImagePadding -> 30, Background -> LightGray]
```

[image: Output of the previous command]

To make the frame thicker or asymmetric, use the standard ImagePadding syntax. You can also add other options such as AspectRatio to passpartout.

In the passepartout function, I use AbsoluteOptions to extract the PlotRange that determines the "passepartout opening." You could replace this by Options to speed things up, but the advantage of using AbsoluteOptions is that it also works for arbitrary Graphics, such as

```
p = Graphics[Circle[], Background -> Yellow]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll add another way of combinig a plot with an image :

```
gr = Graphics[{
       Opacity[0.4], Texture[ExampleData[{"AerialImage", "Pentagon"}]], 
       Polygon[{{0, -1}, {2 Pi, -1}, {2 Pi, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
       VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, -1}, {2 Pi, -1}, {2 Pi, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
Show[Plot[ Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}, Frame -> True], gr]
```

[image]

Comment: You needed to rescale the sine curve to fit the image dimensions.  This is not practical.  Why don't you put the image into a `Raster` and position the `Raster` to fill up the whole plot range (`Scaled`)?  Or why don't you tile a `Texture` onto a background `Rectangle`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Good point! Not sure if `Raster` would yield a better solution, since there might be still some arrangements to do. But hope this completely different approach is worthy of note.

Comment: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Prolog -> {{Raster[
     ExampleData[{"AerialImage", "Pentagon"}, "Data"]/
      255., {Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]}]}}, Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to combine a background PlotRange fill using the `Scaled` `Rectangle` approach with `GridLines` by specifying the undocumented option `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`.  If it is desirable to place the plot lines *over* the grid lines we can move or copy the Line primitives into an `Epilog` option.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
gr = LogPlot[
  {5 (80/x)^4, 5 (55/x)^4, 12 (40/x)^4, 15 (80/x)^4, 9 (80/x)^4, 15 (55/x)^4, 9 (55/x)^4},
  {x, 40, 120},
  PlotStyle -> Map[Directive[Thick, ColorData[14]@#] &, {2, 6, 7, 4, 3, 1, 5}],
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {1, 33},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, 0.1},
  Prolog -> {GrayLevel[0.95], Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]},
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
  ImageSize -> 500
];

Show[gr,
  Epilog -> (gr[[1, 1]] /.
    {style__, x_Line} :> {{Black, Opacity[0.5], AbsoluteThickness[3], x}, style, x})]
```

Comment: This is promising. Is there also a way to get the plot legend back on top?

Comment: @Thijs (1) which version of *Mathematica* are you using? (2) Legends are normally placed to the side and should not be an issue; can you give me a code example where you have a problem?

Comment: I use Mathematica 10. You are right. I put the legend inside the plot. How can I share a simplified code example with you? It is too long for a comment.

Comment: @Thijs I am in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica).