# Gridlines of a framed plot with a background cannot be white?

Tags: plotting

Looking at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/changing-the-background-color-of-a-framed-plot), I am reminded of a problem that I was never able to solve with obtaining a particular plot format.

The issue is that `GridLines` sit *behind* anything in `Prolog`. You can have gridlines with a colored background by giving the background a non-zero `Opacity`.

```
Framed@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
  Prolog -> {LightGray, Opacity[0.5], 
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
  GridLines -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

But if the gridlines are to be white, this isn't feasible, it seems.

```
Framed@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
  Prolog -> {LightGray, Opacity[0.5], 
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
  GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White]]
```

[image]

Yes, you can use the undocumented option `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177607/758485), but then the gridlines go on top of the plot line as well as the background.

```
Framed@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
  Prolog -> {LightGray, Opacity[0.5], 
    Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, 
  GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], 
  Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to reorder the `Prolog` background or the gridlines somehow, so that white gridlines shock, but the gridlines don't go over the plotted function?

Try as I might I was never able to replicate this format (the axis numbers *inside* the frame are a whole other question).

[image]

Comment: Please see my edits.  The inability to resize overlays has always been bugging me.  It turns out it is possible.

Comment: Now in V10 `GridLinesInFront` is documented in [Graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Slightly hackish, but you could use `Epilog` to get the curve on top of the grid, e.g.

```
pl = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}][[1]];

Plot[ Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, Frame -> True,
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White],
 Prolog -> {{LightGray, Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}},
 Epilog -> pl]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Following Mr.Wizard's and Szabolcs' suggestions, an more elegant solution would be:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White]];

Graphics[{}, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 Epilog -> plot[[1]], 
 Prolog -> {{LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}}, 
 Sequence @@ Options[plot]]
```

This has the advantage that the plot is only generated once. It should work for any plot that doesn't have any `Prolog`'s or `Epilog`'s of itself.

You can even build it into a nice custom function:

```
myPlot[x_, range_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{plot = 
    Plot[x, range, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
     GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], 
     opts]},
  Graphics[{}, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
   Epilog -> plot[[1]], 
   Prolog -> {{LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}},
    Sequence @@ Options[plot] ] ]

myPlot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Or an extended version:

```
myPlot[x_, type_, range_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{plot = 
    Switch[type, Plot, 
     type[x, range, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
      GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], 
      opts],
     ParametricPlot, 
     type[x, range, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
      GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], 
      opts],
     ListPlot, 
     type[x, PlotRange -> range, Frame -> True, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, 
      GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], 
      opts],
     ListLinePlot, 
     type[x, PlotRange -> range, Frame -> True, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, 
      GridLinesStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], opts]
     ]},
  Graphics[{}, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
   Epilog -> plot[[1]], 
   Prolog -> {{LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}},
    Sequence @@ Options[plot] ] ]

myPlot[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 
  100], ListLinePlot, {Automatic, Full}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: Why am I not surprised? +1 :-)

Comment: Very nice, +1. With ideas from all three answers, how about `Graphics[{},
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> White,
 Epilog -> plot[[1]],
 Prolog -> {{LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}},
 Sequence @@ Options[plot]
 ]` ?  This ought to work for any `plot` that does not have a `Prolog` or `Epilog` or grid lines and it does not double graphics.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard my only (minor) gripe with your solution is that it plots two curves on top of each other (which is why I used `PlotStyle -> None` in `pl2`), but @Szabolcs solution would solve that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've already edited my solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you defined a plotting function instead of a function which takes any graphics object and lifts the content above the grid lines while shading the background?

Answer (score 4):

This is non-ideal for so many reasons, but (at least in the front end) it does what you describe:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True]

Overlay[{
  Graphics[{}, Sequence @@ Options[plot], 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> White, 
   Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}
   ],
  Show[plot, FrameStyle -> Opacity[0]]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When it comes to exporting / copying / resizing, it becomes increasingly inconvenient though.  I think I would generate my own grid lines just to avoid having to deal with a non-Graphics object.

**EDIT:**

Here's a hack to at least let you resize it interactively:

```
Pane[
 Overlay[{
   Graphics[{}, Sequence @@ Options[plot],
    Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> White, 
    Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]},
    ImageSize -> Full],
   Show[plot, FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], ImageSize -> Full]
   }],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 AppearanceElements -> {"ResizeArea"}
]
```

**EDIT 2:**

Better resizing.  Just don't right click -> Save As ... It'll save only one graphic.

```
DynamicModule[{sz = Medium},
 Overlay[{
   Graphics[{}, Sequence @@ Options[plot],
    Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> White, 
    Prolog -> {LightGray, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]},
    ImageSize -> Dynamic[sz]],
   Show[plot, FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], ImageSize -> Dynamic[sz]]
   }, All, 2]
 ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not draw the gridlines in `Prolog` too?

```
Module[{origplot,
       xglst = Range[0, 5 Pi/4, Pi/8], 
       yglst = Range[-1, 1, 1/5],
       xpglst, ypglst, gridlines,
       xrm, xrM, yrm, yrM, paddingTable, pl, pr, pb, pt},
       origplot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5 Pi/4},
                       PlotStyle -> Thickness[.005],
                       Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {xglst, yglst, {}, {}},
                       Prolog -> {GrayLevel[.9], Rectangle[Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}
                      ];
       {{xrm, xrM}, {yrm, yrM}} = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[origplot, PlotRange];
       paddingTable = PlotRangePadding /. AbsoluteOptions[origplot, PlotRangePadding] /. Scaled -> Identity;
       {{pl, pr}, {pb, pt}} = If[Head[#] === List, #, {#, #}] & /@ paddingTable;
       xpglst = pl + (1 - pl - pr) (xglst - xrm)/(xrM - xrm);
       ypglst = pb + (1 - pb - pt) (yglst - yrm)/(yrM - yrm);
       gridlines = {Thickness[.01], White,
                    Line[{Scaled[{#, 0}], Scaled[{#, 1}]}] & /@ xpglst,
                    Line[{Scaled[{0, #}], Scaled[{1, #}]}] & /@ ypglst};
       origplot /. (Prolog -> expr_) :> (Prolog -> Join[expr, gridlines])
      ]
```

which will give

[image]

The key point is calculating `Scaled` position of the gridlines from `PlotRange` and `PlotRangePadding`.

btw. I noticed that the format of `FrameTicks` described in Help, which is `{{left,right},{bottom,top}}`, will cause the `AbsoluteOptions` alarming, while a format as `{bottom, left, top, right}` will work fine. Wondering is this a bug? (maybe I should ask in a sole question?)