# Labels and tickmarks inside Frame

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, options, ticks

Is there a way to force Plot and related functions to place the tick labels inside, rather than outside a frame?  For example, consider,

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

When this line is executed, the tick labels are outside the bottom and left edges of the frame:

[image]

Is there an easy way to move them to the inside?

(Why place tick labels inside the frame, you ask?  I would like to export plots to PDF in a specified absolute size, so that one major tick on the plot is exactly 1 cm on the printout.  If the labels were not placed on the outside, padding the image, this could be easily done using `ImageSize`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6203586/1224002).)

Comment: You can fix the size of the graphic and the plot area simultaneously using `ImagePadding` as well as `ImageSize`. But some organizations use this style for their graphs so it would be useful to replicate.

Comment: Ted, do you mean something like the last graph in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2289/8)?

Comment: Nevertheless it would be nice to know if tick labels could be placed inside the plot without too much hacking.

Comment: @Verbeia, yes, the arrangement of the y-frame labels in last graph in [the question you linked to](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2289/556) is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,
 Epilog -> {Table[Text[i, {i, -1}, {0, -1}], {i, Range[0, 10, 2]}],
  Table[Text[NumberForm[i, {2, 1}], {0, i}, {-1, 0}], {i, Range[-1, 1, .5]}]},
 FrameTicksStyle -> (FontOpacity -> 0),
 ImagePadding -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Much more concise than I had thought possible: thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of an easy way, but with the help of `Epilog`, `Inset` and `Scaled` (the latter using a combo of absolute coordinates and scaled offsets) it's quite doable:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{None, {{-1, ""}, {0, ""}, {1, ""}}}, {{{0, ""}, {Pi, 
      ""}, {2 Pi, ""}, {3 Pi, ""}}, None}}, 
  Epilog ->
  {
   Inset[0, Scaled[{0, -0.45}, {0, 0}]],
   Inset[\[Pi], Scaled[{0, -0.45}, {\[Pi], 0}]],
   Inset[2 \[Pi], Scaled[{0, -0.45}, {2 \[Pi], 0}]],
   Inset[3 \[Pi], Scaled[{0, -0.45}, {3 \[Pi], 0}]],
   Inset[-1, Scaled[{0.95, 0}, {0, -0.99}]],
   Inset[0, Scaled[{0.95, 0}, {0, 0}]],
   Inset[1, Scaled[{0.95, 0}, {0, 0.99}]]
   },
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 14}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]