# Is it possible to position ticklabels on the negative y axis on its right side?

Tags: plotting, visualization, ticks

Is it possible to position ticklabels on negative $y$ axis on its right side? Ticklabels on positive $y$ axis should remain as usual:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2601/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: These are Input/Output characteristics of scalar quantization. When these diagrams are small, the lebels and the curves tend to overlap!

Answer (score 16):

Here's one idea.  Notice that the tick-marks are flipped as well.

```
p = Plot[Round[x], {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> Thick];

ticks = Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[p];

{yticks, labels} =
   Replace[
     ticks[[2]],
     {a_?Negative, b_, c_, x__} :> {a, Sow@Text[b, {0.3, a}];, -c, x},
     1
   ] // Reap;

Show[p, Graphics[labels], Ticks -> {ticks[[1]], yticks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What about the x axis?

Comment: +1 Nice idea! Why do + and - minor $y$-ticks have different lengths? And why does the $y$-tick at +3.5 seem longer than the one at +3.0? Are these rasterization artefacts?

Comment: @István thanks.  I believe it is a rasterization artifact as it appears even at large sizes.

Comment: @Ajasja the OP asked for the *y axis* modification.  You could do the same thing for only *x* (`ticks[[2]]` -> `ticks[[1]]` & `{0.3, a}` -> `{a, 0.3}`) or for both in two steps.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, sloppy reading, I was just looking at the example image. +1.

Answer (score 10):

Lots of magic numbers, no real scalability and rather specific solution for the given case, but it shows how you can build your own tick function easily from scratch. Since I don't think there is any way to finetune the `Axes`/`AxesStyle`/`Frame` options to suit your needs, this is the best I could suggest at the moment. Or you might want to use David Park's [`` Presentations` ``](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/435/89) package or the [`` CustomTicks` ``](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/429/89) package by Mark Caprio to specify aesthetic tick positions for any range (thanks Szabolcs).

```
{minX, maxX} = {minY, maxY} = {-5, 5}; (* range *)
{xO, yO} = {0, 0}; (* origo *)
d = .2; (* tick length *)
step = 1; (* tick step *)
offset = 1.5; (* tick label offset *)

Plot[IntegerPart@x, {x, minX, maxX}, Exclusions -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{minX, maxX}, {minY, maxY}}, Axes -> False, 
 Epilog -> {
   Black, Line[{{minX, yO}, {maxX, yO}}], Line[{{xO, minY}, {xO, maxY}}],
   Table[{
     Line@{{i, yO}, {i, yO + d}},
     Text[i, {i, yO + d}, {0, -offset}]
     }, {i, minX, xO - 1, step}],(* -x *)
   Table[{
     Line@{{i, yO}, {i, yO - d}},
     Text[i, {i, yO - d}, {0, offset}]
     }, {i, xO + 1, maxX, step}],(* +x *)
   Table[{
     Line@{{xO, i}, {xO + d, i}},
     Text[i, {xO + d, i}, {-offset, 0}]
     }, {i, minY, yO - 1, step}],(* -y *)
   Table[{
     Line@{{xO, i}, {xO - d, i}},
     Text[i, {xO - d, i}, {offset, 0}]
     }, {i, yO + 1, maxY, step}] (* +y *)
   }, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@.05]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could use the CustomTicks package to generate tick positions, it'd make the solution a little easier to modify/reuse.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I never used that package, but it seems very useful. Actually, I think it worths its own answer, and would be a perfect starting point for people willing to learn how to use it! So if you have any knowledge, please post your CustomTicks-based solution!

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree, your suggestion would make a good answer on it's own.

Answer (score 7):

This needs some tweaking, but could be a starting point for a more general solution. The idea is to plot the bottom left quadrant of the plot with a `Frame` top and right, and the top right quadrant of the plot with a `Frame` bottom and left. Then `Inset` those into the complete plot.

```
bottomleft=Plot[Sin[x],{x,-4,4},Frame->{False,False,True,True}, 
  FrameTicks->All,PlotRange->{{Automatic,0},{Automatic,0}}];
topright=Plot[Sin[x],{x,-4,4},Frame->{True,True,False,False},
  FrameTicks->All,PlotRange->{{0,Automatic},{0,Automatic}}];

Plot[Sin[x],{x,-4,4},Ticks->False,
  Epilog->{Inset[bottomleft,{0,0},{0,0},Scaled[0.58]],Inset[topright,{0,0},{0,0},Scaled[0.58]]}]
```

[image]

Clearly there is a problem with all the ticks at the origin, and the insets had to be scaled by trial and error, but there might be a way to automate that.

Comment: Devious workaround.