# How to change the position of numbers on plot

Tags: plotting

[image: Example of problem]

How to change the position of numbers in axes on plot? I want to see the numbers on the x-axis over it, not under it as it is now to have them clearly visible.

Comment: You can consider using frames instead of axes (look up `Frame`), and also take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6395/12)