# Mathematica flip the axes ticks (negative values) to other side

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have a plot as shown,
[image]

I want to change the axes ticks of the negative values as shown below,
[image]

I went through [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/is-it-possible-to-position-ticklabels-on-the-negative-y-axis-on-its-right-side) post and with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6399) answer, I am able to do only for Y-axis. Can someone please let me know how can I do this for both axes?.

Note: I also tried the comments from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6399) answer for X-axis but that approach is not working.

If there is any other simple ways, please let me know.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Modified Mr. Wizard's code slightly, [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/8NWfU8We)  - seems to as you wish

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thanks a lot @JasonB. I didn't remove the ticks[[1]] in show function and that caused all the issues. Again thanks a lot. One more thing, If I do this, the font style between negative and positive ticks are different. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Never mind... Got it by adding Style[xlabels, ...] in the show function. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this isn't as robust as I would like, but it works decently on many test cases.  I wish there was a way of extracting the automatic tick placement so that you could just reverse it,

```
flipNegativeTicks[plot_] := 
 Module[{ticks, xticks, yticks, xlabels, ylabels, xpos, ypos, range},
  ticks = Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plot];
  range = Charting`get2DPlotRange@plot;
  {ypos, xpos} = Last /@ range/17;

  {yticks, ylabels} = 
   Replace[ticks[[2]], {a_?Negative, b_, c_, x__} :> {a, 
       Sow@Text[b, {ypos, a}];, -c, x}, 1] // Reap;
  {xticks, xlabels} = 
   Replace[ticks[[1]], {a_?Negative, b_, c_, x__} :> {a, 
       Sow@Text[b, {a, xpos}];, -c, x}, 1] // Reap;
  Show[plot, Graphics[{xlabels, ylabels}], Ticks -> {xticks, yticks}, 
   PlotRange -> Charting`get2DPlotRange@plot]
  ]

flipNegativeTicks@Plot[40 Sin[x/20], {x, -10, 70}]

flipNegativeTicks@Plot[Sinc[x/10000], {x, -50000, 70000}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful. I am beginner here, can you please help me to get tick labels as -10.0, 10.0, 20.0 etc in place -10. , 10. , 20.

Comment: @souravc -  do you want to do that while also using the trick from this post, or just as a separate issue?

Comment: yes, when I am using the trick described in the above post I want to get tick labels as -10.0, 10.0, 20.0 etc in place -10. , 10. , 20. Should I ask a separate question?

Comment: @souravc - if you take the trick here, add the line `ticks = ticks /. {a_, b_?NumericQ, c__} :> {a, 
     NumberForm[SetPrecision[b, 4], 3], c};` after the line where `ticks` is defined, then the very first example plot here will do what you are looking for.  This isn't versatile though, since for the second example it spits out an error because the NumberForm doesn't give enough zeros.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working for me. I will keep in mind the probable loopholes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a motivating post. I'm sure others could do much better  and I have not refined it (no time):

```
tf[n_?Positive] := Table[{j, j, {0.02, 0.02}}, {j, 1, n}]
tf[n_] := Table[{j, "", {0.02, 0.02}}, {j, n, -1}]
txth[{l_, u_}, p_, col_] := 
 Text[Style[#, col], {#, p}] & /@ Range[l, u]
txtv[{l_, u_}, p_, col_] := 
 Text[Style[#, col], {p, #}] & /@ Range[l, u]
gl[{l_, u_}, s_] := 
 Table[{j, {Gray, Thick}}, {j, l, u}]~Join~
  Table[{j, LightGray}, {j, l, u, s}]
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, 
  Ticks -> {tf[-6]~Join~tf[6], tf[-3]~Join~tf[3]}, 
  Epilog -> {txth[{-6, -1}, p, Red]~Join~txtv[{-3, -1}, p, Red]}, 
  GridLines -> {gl[{-6, 6}, 0.2], gl[{-4, 4}, 0.2]}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}], {p, 0.1, 0.5}]
```

[image]