# How can I move these numbers to the right side of the y axis?

Tags: plotting

How can I move these numbers to the right side of the y axis?

 (preferably not using frame)

```
Plot[1 + x^2, {x, -5, 0}]
```

[image]

Here is my orginal problem. I tried my best to create a simple minimal working example for this. 
 It would be nice if there is a way to move the numbers with minimal changes as I did use a lot of style settings for axes and numbers.

```
polygon = {{0, 0}, {0, 1.5}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 0}, {0, 0}};
myfunc[myfunctions_, polygon_, {xmin_, xmax_, ymin_, ymax_}] := 
 Module[{plot1, plot2, points},
  
  plot1 = 
   ListLinePlot[polygon, 
     GridLines -> {Range[xmin, xmax, 1/2], Range[ymin, ymax, 1/2]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
     FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2`], Pink],
     AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["X", Magnification -> 3], 
       MaTeX["Y", Magnification -> 3]}, 
     Ticks -> {({#1, 
           MaTeX[#1, "DisplayStyle" -> False, 
            Magnification -> 3]} &) /@ 
        Range[xmin, 
         xmax], ({#1, 
           MaTeX[#1, "DisplayStyle" -> False, 
            Magnification -> 3]} &) /@ Range[ymin, ymax, 1]}, 
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], 
     GridLines -> {Range[xmin, xmax, 1], Range[xmin, xmax, 1]}, 
     ImageSize -> 800] /. _Line -> Sequence[];
  plot2 = 
   Plot[myfunctions, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], CapForm["Round"]], 
    AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["X", Magnification -> 2], 
      MaTeX["Y", Magnification -> 2]}, 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], ImageSize -> 800];
  Show[plot1, plot2, AspectRatio -> 1]
  ]
```

Now if you excute this:

```
myfunc[{-x, -((1 + x^2)/(x - 3)), 2 - x}, polygon, {-3, 0, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use a frame rather than axes. This should be as simple as changing all axis references to "frame". For instance, `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`, `FrameLabel` instead of `AxesLabel`, etc.

Comment: @MarcoB I just tried but the numbers are much smallers and look bad. I can increase the size manually but I don't know how to keep it exactly the same as before.  I want to keep everything same, just moving the numbers to the right.

Comment: After all of this, I decided to export the image and numbers, titles and add it in visio which is much easier to do!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Assuming that your objection to `Frame` is just to avoid frames to the left and above:

```
Plot[1 + x^2, {x, -5, 0}, 
 Frame -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}},
 FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The optional argument `type` with any value other then `"Axes"` will switch to a `Frame`

```
Needs["MaTeX`"];
```

**EDIT 2:** Placing labels on the axes instead of frames

```
myfunc[myfunctions_, polygon_, {xmin_, xmax_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
 type_ : "Axes"] := Module[
  {plot1, plot2, points, xticks, yticks},
  {xticks, yticks} = {
    ({#1, MaTeX[#1, "DisplayStyle" -> False,
         Magnification -> 3]} &) /@ Range[xmin, xmax],
    ({#1, MaTeX[#1, "DisplayStyle" -> False,
         Magnification -> 3]} &) /@ Range[ymin, ymax]};
  plot1 = ListLinePlot[polygon,
     GridLines ->
      {Range[xmin, xmax, 1/2], Range[ymin, ymax, 1/2]},
     PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}},
     PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01],
     Filling -> {1 -> Axis},
     FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2`], Pink],
     AxesLabel -> {
       MaTeX["X", Magnification -> 3],
       MaTeX["Y", Magnification -> 3]},
     FrameLabel -> None,
     Ticks -> {xticks, yticks},
     FrameTicks -> {{None, yticks}, {xticks, None}},
     TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20],
     GridLines ->
      {Range[xmin, xmax, 1], Range[ymin, ymax, 1]},
     ImageSize -> 500,
     If[type === "Axes",
      {Axes -> True, Frame -> False},
      {Axes -> False, Frame -> {{False, True}, {True, False}}}]] /. 
    _Line -> Sequence[];
  plot2 = 
   Plot[myfunctions, {x, xmin, xmax}, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.01], CapForm["Round"]]];
  axesLabels = Graphics[{
     Text[MaTeX["X", Magnification -> 3], Scaled[{1.1, 0}]],
     Text[MaTeX["Y", Magnification -> 3], Scaled[{1, 1.07}]]}];
  Show[plot1, plot2,
   If[type === "Axes", {}, axesLabels], AspectRatio -> 1,
   ImagePadding -> {{25, 70}, {50, 50}},
   PlotRangeClipping -> False]]
```

Example,

```
myfunc[{-x, -((1 + x^2)/(x - 3)), 2 - x}, polygon, 
 {-3, 0, 0, 5}, "Frame"]
```

[image]

Comment: I did set a lot of styles for axies and these numbers so I don't want to use frame so I'll have to do it again for frame.

Comment: Edit your question to reflect the actual problem you are trying to resolve. In is not clear why the solution involves more than additionally changing one word.

Comment: I just updated it.

Comment: How can I keep "X" and "Y" on the corners as the orginal? 
This is very nice but I just want to keep it consistent with many images I did previously.

Answer (score 4):

Applying Mr.Wizard's method from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6399/363)

```
p = Plot[1 + x^2, {x, -5, 0}];
ticks = Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[p];
{yticks, labels} = Replace[ticks[[2]], {a_, b_, {c_, x_}} :>
     {a, Sow@Text[b, {0.2, a}];, {-c, x}}, 1] // Reap;
Show[p, Graphics[labels /. "0" -> ""], Ticks -> {ticks[[1]], yticks},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, 0.3}, Automatic}]
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work on my PC, 12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Comment: It works on my another PC with 13.0.1 but how would you apply it to my orginal code? I tried but couldn't make it work.

Comment: There are no brackets around `{c_, x_}` and `{-c, x}` in Mr.Wizard original code, so omitting them might get it working in 12.