# Position tick labels on box sides of the axis

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

I use ticks label both for scale (0.8, .9, 1.0, ... ) and for marking specific values of interest (with custom text). I'd like the numbers to be above the axis and the text below it. I was able to change the direction of the tick but the text still remains below the axis.

[image]

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Would be great if you could provide the code producing that picture :)

Comment: and 16 months later, I would say to use this answer:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2608/9490

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Labels and tickmarks inside Frame](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/labels-and-tickmarks-inside-frame)