# Frame and white background not working (all other colours are fine)

Tags: graphics, bugs, color

**Bug introduced in 6 and fixed in 7**

---

Though my question my be related to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2289/gridlines-of-a-framed-plot-with-a-background-cannot-be-white), it doesn't look like it can easily be solved in the same way, so I hope not to be double-posting.

I am trying to insert a framed number/text into a graphics using `Epilog`. The text (black), the background (white) and the frame (coloured, e.g. orange) shall be of different colours.

As a minimal working example, the following code indeed produces the desired result:

```
Graphics[{
  LightGray, Disk[], 
  Inset[Framed[Style[ToString[text], Black, 50],
    Background -> Pink, 
    FrameStyle -> {Orange}]]}]
```

[image: first example]

Yet, when I try to change the background colour to `White`, it simply is ignored!

```
Graphics[{
  LightGray, Disk[], 
  Inset[Framed[Style[ToString[text], Black, 50],
    Background -> White, 
    FrameStyle -> {Orange}]]}]
```

[image: second example]

I know I could also apply the `Background` to the `Inset` rather than to the `Framed`, but that unfortunately results in the background colour slightly extending beyond the frame. I am using Mathematica version 6.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: well it works in my case, I get a white background, using exactly your code (MMA 9.0.1)

Comment: Maybe I should add I am still on Mathematica 6. But simply adding a white background shouldn't really require state-of-the-art software, it seems to me...

Comment: Seems to be a version problem. It works well for MMA 8.0.1 and 9.0.1.

Comment: Well then I guess all I can hope for is some other user still on v6 who can figure a workaround. For know, the only easy solution that works for me is setting the colour to `RGBColor[0.999, 0.999, 0.999]`, which turns out pretty white.

Comment: What happens if you evaluate `Graphics[{LightGray, Disk[], Text[Framed[Style["text", Black, 50],  Background -> White, FrameStyle -> {Orange}]]}]`?

Comment: @m_goldberg Negative, unfortunately (still only works with non-white colours).

Comment: What about an oh so slightly off-white gray value?

Comment: @YvesKlett, that's what I ended up doing as a workaround, see my comment above on `RGBColor[0.999, 0.999, 0.999]`.

Comment: ACK... sorry, I read over that :-)

Comment: It also works in *Mathematica* 7, so I have tagged it as a bug in version 6. I hope you managed to update your version since asking this question.