# How to make Epilog render behind the main plot

Tags: plotting

Consider this example:

```
data = Table[{i, i + 20 Sin[RandomReal[-i, i]][[1]]}, {i, 1, 1000}];
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1000}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

It can be seen that the points are rendered over the main plot and makes it invisible.

How to control the layers of plot so that to send a layer backward or to bring it forward.

Comment: Use `Prolog`, not `Epilog`.

Comment: @m_goldberg Great, thanks.

Comment: @m_goldberg This question may seem simple, but I'm not sure if it has been asked before. Why don't post that as an answer?

Comment: Seems like we (as a site) have been on a question-closing rampage recently :/ I'd say keep it open and post the answer, too.

Comment: "`Prolog` is an option for graphics functions which gives a list of graphics primitives to be rendered before the main part of the graphics is rendered."  That seems pretty clear to me.  And `Prolog` is the first "See Also" link in the docs for `Epilog`.  I agree with the close votes.  Perhaps there are other questions unduly closed.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I propose closing this as "already answered here": [(4368)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4368).  What do you think?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Somehow I missed your ping.  I agree, the answer to this question is in Timo's post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated in the comments, a good solution is to use `Prolog`, rather than `Epilog`. The difference, of course, is that Graphics directives in `Epilog` are laid down on *top* of the plot, while Graphics directives in `Prolog` are laid down *under* the plot. Here's a simple example illustrating this difference.

```
Column[Framed[Plot[x^2, {x, -1.3, 1.3},
  # -> {Lighter[Gray], EdgeForm[Black],
   Polygon[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]},
 ImageSize -> 300, PlotLabel -> #]] & /@
{Epilog, Prolog}]
```

[image]