# PlotRangeClipping not working correctly with small ImageSize and PDF-export

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, export, pdf-format

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 13.0.1**

---

Although *Mathematica* has some nice plotting capabilities, there are some things which are annoying me.

I like to export a `Graphics` to PDF for use in $\LaTeX$. I like to a have an `ImageSize` of the PDF file, which corresponds to the image size in my document (e.g. 6 cm). I don't like to scale my image in $\LaTeX$.

When exporting to PDF the `PlotRangeClipping` does not work as expected (especially when having a small `ImageSize`):

```
cm=72/2.54;
p1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[.1]}], FaceForm[], Disk[]},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  ImageSize -> 6 cm]
Export["p1.pdf", p1]

p2 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[.1]}], FaceForm[], Disk[]},
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  PlotRangeClipping -> True,
  ImageSize -> 26 cm]
Export["p2.pdf", p2]
```

While the `PlotRangeClipping` for in the second generated file (p2.pdf) is more or less okay (not perfect),

[image: p2.pdf magnified]

there are serious problems in p1.pdf:

[image: p1.pdf magnified]

Is this a bug?

Is there a way to have an acceptable `PlotRangePadding` with a small `ImageSize`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason why this overhang appears is that the `Thickness` of the line marking the edge of the `Disk` is not counted as something that needs to be clipped (although it should). The line itself (the center of the thick red line) is clipped correctly.

But of course the result looks very clumsy, and it can only be eliminated if the line thickness is made as small as the thickness of the `Frame`. So in order to get a prettier result, you have to mask the overhanging line thickness manually. Here is how you could do it:

```
p1 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[.1]}], FaceForm[], Disk[]}, 
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

Show[p1, With[{d = .2},
  Graphics[
   {White, FilledCurve[
     {
      {Line[{{-d, -d}, {-d, 1 + d}, {1 + d, 1 + d}, {1 + d, -d}}]},
      {Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}
      }
     ]}
   ]
  ], ImageSize -> 6 cm]
```

The `FilledCurve` is a square with a hole in it, like a picture frame with a with border of thickness `d = .2` in plot units.

The exported `PDF` looks like this:

[image: exported pdf]

**Edit to make it work independently of `PlotRange`**

To make the cropping frame resize automatically with the `PlotRange`, I went back to the question [Changing the background color of a framed plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2261/245) and saw that there was an [answer by István Zachar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4371/245) that also uses `FilledCurve` and applies `Scaled` and `ImageScaled` to the rectangle borders. Using that approach directly still lets some of the red arc peek through in the notebook display, so I combined that approach with my above choice of an extra width `d`, and that should work for arbitrary `PlotRange`:

```
Show[p1, With[{d = .2}, 
  Graphics[{White, 
    FilledCurve[{{Line[
        ImageScaled /@ {{-d, -d}, {-d, 1 + d}, {1 + d, 
           1 + d}, {1 + d, -d}}]}, {Line[
        Scaled /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}}]}]], 
 ImageSize -> 6 cm]
```

For more games that you can play with `FilledCurve`, see e.g. [Filling a polygon with a pattern of insets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3723/245).

Comment: Also nice! Is there a way to make this procedure independent of the PlotRange?

Comment: Yes, I added an update to make that approach work for any `PlotRange`.

Comment: Looking at the output postscript (EPS which does the same thing) mathematic sends the full curve and lets the postcript engine do the clippimng. I suspect the core issue is that mathematica is (unnecessarily) rounding the clip path values to integers.

Comment: @george2079 That's interesting, I didn't look at the details. Can I add this to my answer?

Comment: Yes! Now it is working solution. Thx. (Although I hope that Wolfram will fix these kind of issues with plotting one day!)

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to the obtain the PDF's files you want without the problems you showed. I am going by the assumption that there is no simple Plot option we are overlooking here, so this solution uses Inskscape to get the pdf file without the clipping you show.

1) Download the install free software  [Inskscape](http://inkscape.org/download/)

2) Export the images you want to [svg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) and not to pdf

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Export["p2.svg", p2]
Export["p1.svg", p1]
```

3) Open Inskscape and read p1.svg , then do save as and select PDF and make sure to use the "export area is drawing option"

[image: Mathematica graphics]

4) Now open the p1.pdf, and it will be OK

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do the same for p2.pdf :

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've put the pdf files p1.pdf and p2.pdf [here](http://12000.org/tmp/080413) for you to check.

Comment: Nice! I didn't try svg export yet, but it looks promising! This can even be [automated](http://superuser.com/questions/303727/free-linux-command-line-tool-to-convert-svg-to-pdf-and-or-some-commonly-used-bit)!

Comment: Look at the lower left corner of p1.pdf. The problem is still there I think... (I'd managed to get this far with `ImageSize -> {w,h}`...