# Exported PDF figure looks different in Apple's Preview than in Adobe PDF Reader

Tags: export, mac-os-x

I'm trying to export figures into pdf, and the results looks good in Preview, but very bad in Adobe pdf reader. I'm using Mathematica version 8 on Mac 10.8.5. The Preview version is 6.0.1 (765.6) and the Adobe PDF Reader version is 11.0.04.63.

For a simple three point polygon, it looks good in both pdf viewer

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.15], EdgeForm[Lighter[Black, 0.8]], 
  Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, Boxed -> False]
Export["~/Downloads/12345.pdf", %, ImageResolution -> 100]
```

[image]

but for polygon with more points, it looks very bad in Adobe reader

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.15], EdgeForm[Lighter[Black, 0.8]], 
  Polygon@Join[{{-1, 0, 0}}, 
    Table[{-1, t, Cos[t]^2}, {t, 0, \[Pi]/2, 0.01}]]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.5}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Right]
Export["~/Downloads/1234.pdf", %, ImageResolution -> 100]
```

[image]

Why they looks different in the two pdf viewer and is there a way to fix it so that pdf figure works in both pdf viewers?

Comment: Looks bad in Adobe Reader? Strange... usually, my issues are with Preview. FWIW, it looks equally bad on both viewers here (same versions, with mma 9.0.1).

Comment: For a workaround, I tried the `Export["1234.svg", %]` instead, then used `inskscape` to convert to PDF and the problem does not seem to show up on my screen. But you can try it, as a workaround.  Here are the steps http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29797/plotrangeclipping-not-working-correctly-with-small-imagesize-and-pdf-export

Comment: *Mathematica* 8 often produces PDF files with syntactic errors in the code. You can use free [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) utilities to fix this.

Comment: Another useful tool for converting svg to something more useful is [cairosvg](http://cairosvg.org/).

Comment: I'd agree that this looks like an (opacity-related?) bug in Mathematica v. 9.0.1 on Mac OS X.