# PDF export: Lines extending past plot frame area

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, export, pdf-format

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 13.0.1**

---

I recognized recently that a lot of my PDF exported plots have lines extending past the actual (framed) plot area. Here is a simple example:

```
p = ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x, 2 x^2}, {x, -1, 1, .01}],
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}
  ]
Export["test2.pdf", p]
```

The results looks like this (screenshot):

[image]

and if we zoom-in to the top edge:

[image]

Can this be avoided? The effect is not visible in PNG exports, but I prefer working with vector graphics.

Comment: Look around PlotRangePadding and PlotRangeClipping

Comment: @Rom38, Thanks, I forgot to mention, I tried `PlotRangePadding -> None` as well as `PlotRangeClipping -> False` and `PlotRangeClipping -> True`, with no improvement.

Comment: `PlotRangePadding->Scaled[0.01]` can solve the problem with intersection at the top-edge but the left side is still problematic..

Comment: I think this is related to the bug [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29797/245), and the fix could also be similar. I'll try to write an answer with a workaround, but the real solution is to get this bug fixed...

Comment: Please report this as a bug to the tech. support.

Comment: I did report it, let's see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29797/245) where it's observed that the magnitude of the overhang depends on the `ImageSize`. In that thread, we decided it's a bug.

A work-around for this bug is to surround the plot by a "picture frame" or "passepartout" that crops the overhanging piece of the curve. Here I try to do that:

```
p = With[{t = .0004, d = .5, background = White}, 
  ListLinePlot[Table[{x, 2 x^2}, {x, -1, 1, .01}], Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Thickness[2 t], Axes -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   Epilog -> {background, 
     FilledCurve[{{Line[
         ImageScaled /@ {{-d, -d}, {-d, 1 + d}, {1 + d, 1 + d}, {1 + d, -d}}]}, 
       {Line[
         Scaled /@ {{-t, -t}, {-t, 1 + t}, {1 + t, 1 + t}, {1 + t, -t}}]}}]}]]
```

The plot is the same as in the question, but the overhang is now hidden in the exported `PDF`. The variable `d` contains the thickness of the buffer zone around the frame that is overwritten with a frame of color `background`. The issue then arises that this also crops half of the plot frame (if `Frame->True` is set). To fix this, I need to specify the frame thickness explicitly. The variable `t` is *half* the desired frame thickness (in scaled coordinates,  not absolute points). With this, I offset the cropping rectangle by `t` so that it shouldn't overlap with the plot frame. In the notebook, it now looks as if there is in fact some undesirable cropping of the frame. But in the exported `PDF`, I don't see any problems: in particular, the frame and the ticks appear to be of the same thickness, as they should be.

To illustrate the cropping I did above, here is a modified plot that intentionally shows the location of the cropping rectangle in orange, to see where the overhang regions are and how they are blotted out:

[image: orange]

You get this plot by changing `background` to `Orange` and exporting to `PDF`.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to have a workaround for some simple plots. In my present case, I have a multi panel scidraw figure with insets and all of that, so manually framing all of them is not really an option.

Comment: I know, your bug report is the only real way forward.