# How can I draw a grid behind graphics without using Plot?

Tags: graphics, grid-lines

I want to a show simple vector summation but I don't know how to draw a grid behind the vectors. I am pretty sure I can do it with *Mathematica* but how?

It should look like this:

[image: Vector summation]

Comment: If you include your code for drawing the vectors, I'm sure we can help you out with drawing the grid.

Answer (score 16):

*Mathematica* has lots of [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) [primitives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsObjects.html) for you to work with, as well as [directives](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html) such as [`Thick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thick.html), [`Dashed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dashed.html), [`Red`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Red.html), etc.  I'll use [`Arrow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Arrow.html) below.

You can specify the value of the [`GridLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridLines.html) option as a function.  Using `GridLines -> Range` will give lines on a 1:1 grid starting from the extreme lower left of the graphic, as set with [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) or determined automatically.

If you want the grid lines to always snap to integer positions, even if the `PlotRange` is not bounded by integer values, you could use:

```
GridLines -> (Range[⌊#⌋, ⌈#2⌉]&)
```

Grid lines on a 2:2 grid can be had with `Range[⌊#⌋, ⌈#2⌉, 2] &`, etc.

I would construct a function such as this:

```
draw[a : {x_, y_}, b : {X_, Y_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Graphics[{
    {Thick, Blue, Dashed, Arrow[{a, {X, y}}], Arrow[{{X, y}, b}]},
    {Thick, Red, Arrow[{a, b}]}
   },
   opts,
   GridLines -> (Range[⌊#⌋, ⌈#2⌉]&),
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, LightBlue]
 ]
```

And use it:

```
draw[{0, 0}, {7, 3}, PlotRangePadding -> 2]
```

[image]

Not included here are the labels that you can add with [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Text.html) or [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html).

For some explanation of the options handling in the defined function see: [Functions with Options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/353/functions-with-options/358#358)

---

This answer is not intended to be a reference for the use of `GridLines`, only an illustration of one use: graph paper style.  Nevertheless Kuba suggests I mention `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}` and I think that's a good idea.  This option draws the grid lines in front of all your graphics except those in the [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html), if it exists.

```
draw[{0, 0}, {7, 3}, PlotRangePadding -> 2, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image]

See my answer to [Changing the background color of the framed region of a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/changing-the-background-color-of-a-framed-plot/10790#10790) for an example that uses both `"GridLinesInFront"` and `Epilog`.

Comment: Mr Wizard, do you have (a link to) an explanation of how your Gridlines function knows whose Slots it should use on evaluation?

Comment: @wilbert the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridLines.html) for GridLines says: "*func* -- a function to be applied to *Xmin*, *Xmax* to get the grid line option"

Comment: I see that, but am wrestling to understand the formal syntax. here func seems to grab the PlotRange of Graphics?

Comment: @wilbert Yes, I believe that is how it works.  I don't think it's spelled out quite that clearly but there are many examples in the documentation, starting with [this one](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GridLines.html#814353806).

Answer (score 10):

`GridLines` works in Graphics

```
Graphics[{
  {Thick, Darker[Red], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]},
  {Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
  {Dashed, Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}]},
  Text[Style["R", Italic, Large], {.5, .5}, {0, -1}],
  Text[Style["\[Theta]", Large], {.2, .1}, {-1, 0}]
  }, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 2}, {-.5, 1.5}}, Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1. I was working on an example just like this one. Only significant difference is I used `PlotRangePadding`, which is independent of where the arrows are positioned. :)

Comment: @Anon Actually `PlotRangePadding` is a good idea; I hope you don't mind if I incorporate that into my answer.