# plot same-area rectangular in a grid page

Tags: plotting

I wish to plot three rectangulars with the same area in a grid page same as below one. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `Graphics` and `Rectangle`?

Comment: [Related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31114/3066) that may help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for $n =60$. Of coure, $n = 4$ does also work.

```
n = 60;
a = Divisors[n];
b = n/a;
Graphics[{
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], 
  MapThread[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {##}] &, {a, b}]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way using `Divisors` with [`RectangleChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RectangleChart.html):

```
n = 60;
RectangleChart[Transpose[{#, n / #} & @ Divisors[n]], 
 ChartLayout -> "Overlapped", ChartStyle -> FaceForm[], Axes -> False]
```

[image]