# How to fill only a plotting area with Background

Tags: graphics, color, options, labeling

With

```
ListLinePlot [
 {13, 6, 2, 2, 3},
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},Background -> GrayLevel@0.95,
 GridLines -> None, ImageSize -> 300,
 ImageMargins -> 0, PlotLabel -> "XYZ",
 Filling -> Bottom, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

I obtained:

[image]

1. I would like to move the `PlotLabel` `"XYZ"` into the upperright corner of the plotting area.
2. The `Background`-option also colors the background of the axes-values and the label, 
   but I only want to color (like in Excel) the actual plotting-area.

I could think of some complicated ways to achieve this, but would like to see a short and handy solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is not elegant but it works...: 1. Generate your background: `data = {13, 6, 2, 2, 3}; background = RegionPlot[x y <= Length[data] Max[data], {x, 1, Length[data]}, {y, 0, Max[data]}, PlotStyle -> GrayLevel@0.95];` 2. Display it together with your plot (implementing Öskå's suggestion): `Labeled[
 Show[background, ListLinePlot[data,AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},GridLines -> None, ImageSize -> 300, ImageMargins -> 0]],"XYZ", {{Top, Right}}]`.

Comment: One of the two questions here is a duplicate of: [Changing the background color of a framed plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2261/245).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put there a `Rectangle` ;)

```
ListLinePlot[{13, 6, 2, 2, 3}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
                               Filling -> Bottom, BaseStyle -> 18,
             Prolog -> {GrayLevel@0.95, Scaled /@ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]},
             Epilog -> {Inset["XYZ", Scaled[{.9, .9}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was having [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HHizJ.png) :( You are way too fast

Comment: I like that solution. (It is better than mine.)

Comment: @Öskå@Kuba - ALMOST what I was looking for. ALMOST, because I would like to see "XYZ" inside the plotting area. Thank you so far. And yes, answers here are very fast :)

Comment: @Kuba I need `AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},` to make it look better, maybe it's just _v8_. [Picture without](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2ekBF.png).

Comment: Or you could add it in your answer, I guess it's not shadowing anything in _v9_.

Comment: @Öskå I don't likw redundant options :)

Answer (score 4):

You can get the background effect you want by double plotting your data. The plot label can be shifted using `Row` and `Spacer`.

```
ListLinePlot[{{13, 6, 2, 2, 3}, {13, 6, 2, 2, 3}},
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0},
  Filling -> {1 -> Bottom, 2 -> Top},
  FillingStyle -> {2 -> GrayLevel @ 0.95},
  ImageSize -> 300,
  ImageMargins -> 0,
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"", "XYZ"}, Spacer[250]]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    Show[{
  ListLinePlot[{13, 6, 2, 2, 3}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
   Filling -> Bottom,
   GridLines -> None, ImageSize -> 300, ImageMargins -> 0, 
   Epilog -> Inset[Style["XYZ", 16], Scaled[{0.9, 0.9}]]],
  Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], Rectangle[{1, 14.5}, {5.05, 0}]}]
  }]
```

Looking as follows:
[image]

If you need the same color below and above the line, remove the option Filling.

Comment: @Kuba - Thanks, Exactly what I needed

Comment: The fact that the rectangle is dependent on the data (`Rectangle[{1, 14.5}, {5.05, 0}]`) is quite bad IMO.

Comment: @Öskå - Thanks for editing (I had preset options early in the program) - I can live with Kuba's solution because the program "knows" the rectangle-values.

Comment: @ Öskå Yes, It is unsatisfactory. It is fast to do though. You just put the stuff inside manipulate and get these numbers within seconds.