# Difference between Prolog and explicit Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

Is there any difference between

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Prolog -> {Pink, Disk[{0, 1}, 1]}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

and

```
Show[Graphics[{Pink, Disk[{0, 1}, 1]}], Plot[x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}], 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> True]
```

The output appears to be identical, and the description of `Prolog` doesn't seem to describe anything different. (I have the same question about `Epilog`).

Comment: No, there isn't any difference. `Show` takes its options from the first argument so you need to specify explicitly all the options of `Plot` to get it right, but you seem to be aware of that. `Options[Plot]` can help. `Epilog` is simpler in that `Graphics` naturally comes after `Plot`. If you want to make sure you can use `FullForm` to compare the end result of the two pieces of code.

Comment: Thanks. Could you turn that into an answer so I can accept and we won't have unanswered questions lying about? (I always forget about using `FullForm` for these kinds of things).

Comment: I was waiting for more careful analysis such as that by m_goldberg and Mr.Wizard. Even though, in the main, the simple analysis provided by my comment is correct (for display purposes), I did not look for all the subtleties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the structure of the expression rather than the way it is displayed.

Let us name the expressions `g1` and `g2` for reference:

```
g1 = Plot[x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, Prolog -> {Pink, Disk[{0, 1}, 1]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> Automatic];

g2 = Show[Graphics[{Pink, Disk[{0, 1}, 1]}], Plot[x^2, {x, -1.5, 1.5}], 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> True];
```

Observe that in `g1` the [`Prolog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) remains an option:

```
Options[g1, Prolog]
```

> ```
> {Prolog -> {RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.5], Disk[{0, 1}, 1]}}
> ```

This means it is not straightforward to combine this with another `Prolog`:

```
Show[g1, Prolog -> {LightBlue, Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

`g2` however can directly receive a `Prolog` without conflict:

```
Show[g2, Prolog -> {LightBlue, Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

The same mechanism applies to [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) as well.

---

### What's the purpose of `Prolog` and `Epilog`?

You remarked:

> So based on [these answers] why would you want to ever use `Prolog` or `Epilog`?

Convenience, mainly.  They let one quickly and easily combine up to three layers of graphics in a single `Plot` expression.  For more complicated constructions a `List` in `Graphics` often works better.

However there are cases where I know of no other way to get the desired output, one being:

- [Changing the background color of the framed region of a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2261/121#10790)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another issue. `PlotRange -> All` does not consider the contents of `Prolog` or `Epilog` when calculating the viewport for the rendered graphics.

The code

```
Show[
  Graphics[{Pink, Disk[{0, 1}, 1.5]}],
  Plot[x^2, {x, -1.75, 1.75},
    PlotStyle -> Thick, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic],
  Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> All
```

renders everything.

[image: all]

while the code

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -1.75, 1.75},
  Prolog -> {Pink, Disk[{0, 1}, 1.5]},
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

doesn't render the pink disk completely because it was specified in a prolog.

[image: part]

Comment: So based on your answer (and @MrWizard's), why would you want to ever use `Prolog` or `Epilog`?